# how to launch an activity with 'sartActivityForResult' from an ItemizedOverlay class

Tags: android, android-activity, overlay, itemizedoverlay

I have this scenario:

- Main activity with one button. Once clicked it launchs 'mapActivity'
- Map activity (extending MapActivity) uses an ItemizedOverlay (extending ItemizedOverlay) class to mark places over the map.

Now, I want to launch another activity from my itemized overlay. I achieved to launch one activity  as standar intent this way:

```
@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint point, MapView mapView) {

     boolean tapped = super.onTap(point, mapView);

    if (!tapped){           
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this.context, EditarLugarActivity.class);
        this.context.startActivity (intent);
    return true;
}
```

EditarLugarActivity is an activity whichs obtain a text input from user. Now, I need to get that text from the Itemized Overlay activity. Context have the value from map activity context and is set in constructor in this way:

```
public MiItemizedOverlay(Context context, Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    this.context = context;

    populate();
}
```

To do this I've tried to use 'sartActivityForResult' instead 'this.content.startActivity(intent) in this way:

```
@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint point, MapView mapView) { 

    boolean tapped = super.onTap(point, mapView);

    if (!tapped){           
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this.context, EditarLugarActivity.class);
        this.context.startActivityForResult (intent,1);
    return true;
}
```

but is not recognized by the compiler. 'this.context' is not working as it work for a simple 'startActivity'

Someone can help me with this? Thanks!

EDIT-
 Adding my MiItemizedOverlay class first line with 'extends':

```
public class MiItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context context; [....]
```

Comment: have you tried it as `intent.setClass(context, EditarLugarActivity.class);` or `intent.setClass(MiItemizedOverlay.this.context, EditarLugarActivity.class);` ? because in your case `this` refer to the method context instead of class and context is field of class instead of `onTap` method

Comment: Thanks for helping. 
I've tried what you are proposing but it not resolve my problem. Still can't call  startActivityForResult function.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext, EditarLugarActivity.class);
    this.context.startActivityForResult (intent);
```

or

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, EditarLugarActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.
I've tried that but 'MiItemizedOverlay' class extends ItemizedOverlay. I can't call 'getApplicationContext' as I can't call startActivityForResult

Answer (score 0):

There is no no method called `startActivityForResult` which takes only one argument.

Use, `context.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);` Here the second argument is the result code which would be returned back to you from `EditarLugarActivity` when `finish()` is called on that activity. You can define your own result code. And then you need to implement `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` in your activity to catch this result code.

**EDIT:**
`StartActivityForResult` method is from Activity class. So you need to call it as below

```
((Activity) this.context).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Make sure that your context is indeed an Activity context, and implement the `onActivtyResult` in the mapActivity.

Comment: Thanks for helping. 
That is a copy-paste mistake... my fault. I was trying to call startActivityForResult as you describe but is 'undefined' and no import suggested by my editor. Same problem when I try to override onActivityResult function. ¿Maybe I'm missing something on MiItemizedOverlay class?

Comment: Please check my edit in the original answer. And you should not face any issue in Overriding the `onActivityResult` method. Make sure to implement that method in mapActivity class.